# Redirect .rar files in a folder to another page with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This may sound like a strange question, but i need to redirect all .rar files in a folder to another file.

Dir:

```
/downloads/
```

I need to redirect all request to any file in the "/downloads/" folder to "somepage.php"

Eg. if you try to go to "/downloads/somefile.rar" or "/downloads/someotherfile.rar" you get redirected to "somepage.php" (this file should not be is not in the downloads folder).

Is this possible?

I have tried this with no luck, this .htaccess is in the /downloads/ folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\.rar$ http://www.domain.com/somepage.php [R, L]
```

Any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: do you want the `*.rar` files to be redirected only from the `download` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*).rar$ http://www.mydomain.com/somepage.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That worked, but i had to empty cache (maybe why my own solution did not work) :-)